# C# VS uninstaller

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, installation

I have created VS installer in VS2010. it works fine. when the program is already installed and you re-run the installer it would prompt for repair and uninstall. this is good. the problem is when I re-build the same exact installer and try to install it on a machine that already has one installed it would not give me the prompt repair and uninstall. Instead it gives me pop up error "Windows Installer: Another version of this product is already installed. Installation of this version cannot continue...." then it asks me to do manual uninstall using Add/Remove program from Control panel.

So there is gotta be something changed/auto generated during the re-build. kind a like key or something that is different from the older version which makes the newer one fails to recognize the older version. anybody knows how to handle this?

Comment: It's been a while since I've done it so I don't remember the details, just that it was a huge pain in the ass.  I think you need some kind of installer wrapper that calls the MSI with some command line properties or something ridiculous.

Comment: What windows installer tools are you using.  Installshield?

Comment: I would stop right now and run away from setup projects (vdproj).  It is deprecated and will no longer be supported by Microsoft.

Comment: huh? this is in vs2010, other project types->Setup and deployment-> VS Installer -> Setup Project. Not supported by MS??

Comment: Moving forward it will not be,  but on the other hand have you set the RemovePreviousVersions property to true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you increase the version it will automatically detect the previous version and handle it as per your configuration on `RemovePrevousVersions` and `DetectNewerInstalledVersion`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

increment your setup project version and set

```
- DetectNewerInstalledVersion = true
- RemovePrevousVersions = true
```

more info : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/winformssetup/thread/717cfce0-3061-400f-9ea3-069f73f3a473

Answer (score 2):

On the properties on the VS Setup project set the `RemovePreviousVersions` to True.  I believe by default it is set to false.  I beleive that would save some time instead of doing it manually.

Also, there is an ProductCode, UpgradeCode, and Version in these properties. These control installation behavior, more information is here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372845(v=VS.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372845%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)

Here are more details:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370579%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)